# Apscheduler cannot stop a scheduled job

Tags: python, apscheduler

I use apscheduler to schedule a job, and expect to run the job everyday from 6am to 7am New York time. The apschdeduler can start at the right time but cannot end the job which keeps running forever. I try to add a for loop to control ending the job after 60 minutes, but it seems still never end.

If you have any idea, please share with me.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pytz

def usny_curtime():
    nyc_datetime = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    time_stamp = nyc_datetime.strftime(fmt)
    return time_stamp

sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone='America/New_York')
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour='6-7', minute = '*', )
def get_stock_data():

    for i in range(0, 60):
            if i == 60:
                sched.remove_job('cron')
                
            start_time = time.time()
            us_time = usny_curtime()
            print("***US time", us_time)
            print("*******START TIME(1)", time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(start_time)))    
            print("i***",i)
            
sched.start()
```

Comment: Your trigger specifies "I want to start this job every minute, from 6:00 to 7:59". Is that really what you intended? The scheduler has no way to stop jobs that are already running. Even if it did, the ID of that job is not `cron` (which you passed to sched.remove_job). Are you sure you read the documentation?

Comment: I just want to run the schedule job for one hour everyday. According to the document https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/cron.html, can define the hour in cron job, see the example.

Comment: The _starting_ hour, yes. You would need to return from the target function after one hour if that is the limit you want to impose on the job. The scheduler will not do that for you.